# CakePHP load all plugins except one using CakePlugin::loadAll()

Tags: cakephp, plugins

I have known that the method `loadAll()` to load all plugins and the method `load('PluginName')` to load a plugin.

```
 * CakePlugin::loadAll(); // Loads all plugins at once
 * CakePlugin::load('DebugKit'); //Loads a single plugin named DebugKit
```

However, my requirement is to load all plugins except one.
For example, I have 5 plugins including DebitKit; I want to load 4 plugins excluding DebitKit. Is it possible to accomplish with `CakePlugin::loadAll()` at one shot.

I'm using Cake 2.1.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is possible with `loadAll` (unless you use `unload` afterwards).

An alternative approach is to specify all the plugins you want to load with: `CakePlugin::load(array('PluginA', 'PluginB'));`.